# Find matching value and show that value and its corresponding values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns B and F, both containing many email addresses. I have a current statement that searches for all matching emails in B and if the email exists in F, it outputs "Y", if no match, the output is "N".

Here is the code: =IF(ISNA(MATCH(F2,B$2:B$50,0)),"N","Y")

How do I alter my statement so that when a match between F and B is found the output value in B and the corresponding row values in A, C, and D are all shown in a new column to the right of F?

Comment: Not sure you need vba. Check the sheet function `VLOOKUP`. As far as I understand your question, you can come with your requirements using this function.

Comment: The match() function returns the position it found the matching data, so use that result with OFFSET() to collect the values you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I think I understand the question, you want to copy the information in columns A/C/D when you return True / Y from your initial formula.

You should be able to use a simple if statement to solve this.

```
=IF(E1="Y", A1, "")
=IF(E1="Y", C1, "")
=IF(E1="Y", D1, "")
```

Here we check if the value in E (I am assuming this is your output column) has returned as a Y. If it does then it will copy the text from A/C/D.

Given that F is your email to match column, B is your array column (list of all emails), and A/C/D are all columns to copy. You can add absolute column references to quickly copy while keeping E as your reference column.